# Where is the definition of system_adc_read() in the esp8266 Arduino code?

Tags: esp8266, adc

Where is the definition of [`uint16 system_adc_read(void)`](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/d24a358817f0c11f7087b3c8acbf24629b15998f/tools/sdk/include/user_interface.h#L119) in the [esp8266 Arduino code](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino)?

I can see it being declared in `Arduino/tools/sdk/include/user_interface.h`, however there seems to be no definition of this. `system_adc_read()` gets called in [`analogRead()`](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/4897e0006b5b0123a2fa31f67b14a3fff65ce561/cores/esp8266/core_esp8266_wiring_analog.c#L33) in `Arduino/cores/esp8266/core_esp8266_wiring_analog.c`

I suspect `system_adc_read()` calls [`system_adc_read_fast()`](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/d24a358817f0c11f7087b3c8acbf24629b15998f/tools/sdk/include/user_interface.h#L120) to read the ADC, but can't actually find it in the code! Could somebody please point me to this? I've been struggling for quite some time.

***Purpose:*** To manipulate the system_adc_read() in ESP8266 to get higher ADC sampling rates. Right now ADC sampling rate is 10ksps. I want it to be more than 30-40ksps.

Comment: esp8266 sdk is not open source

Comment: Oh my god! Thanks for telling me this. So, what are my alternatives here? I've searched for ways to improve the sampling rate, but couldn't get to the desired (30-40 ksps) level.

Comment: try ESP8266 Non-OS SDK API Reference here http://espressif.com/en/support/download/overview?keys=&field_type_tid%5B%5D=14

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "definition" of `uint16 system_adc_read(void)` is inside the compiled archive/object file `libmain.a` inside one of the `NONOSDK` folders which is located in `/tools/sdk/lib/` . The version is selected in `platform.txt`. For example in my platform.txt:

```
# default SDK for all boards
# (generic board overrides this variable)
build.sdk=NONOSDK22x_190703
#build.sdk=NONOSDK22x_191024
#build.sdk=NONOSDK22x_191105
```

Running the `xtensa-lx106-elf-objdump.exe -d` on this file I can find this section inside:

```
00000258 <system_adc_read>:
     258:   020c                    movi.n  a2, 0
     25a:   f0c112                  addi    a1, a1, -16
     25d:   0109                    s32i.n  a0, a1, 0
     25f:   fffc01                  l32r    a0, 250 <system_pp_recycle_rx_pkt+0x18>
     262:   0000c0                  callx0  a0
     265:   fff901                  l32r    a0, 24c <system_pp_recycle_rx_pkt+0x14>
     268:   f42020                  extui   a2, a2, 0, 16
     26b:   1b1207                  beq a2, a0, 28a <system_adc_read+0x32>
     26e:   b30c                    movi.n  a3, 11
     270:   902220                  addx2   a2, a2, a2
     273:   1122e0                  slli    a2, a2, 2
     276:   fff701                  l32r    a0, 254 <system_pp_recycle_rx_pkt+0x1c>
     279:   0000c0                  callx0  a0
     27c:   f42020                  extui   a2, a2, 0, 16
     27f:   00a402                  movi    a0, 0x400
     282:   013027                  bltu    a0, a2, 287 <system_adc_read+0x2f>
     285:   020d                    mov.n   a0, a2
     287:   f42000                  extui   a2, a0, 0, 16
     28a:   0108                    l32i.n  a0, a1, 0
     28c:   10c112                  addi    a1, a1, 16
     28f:   f00d                    ret.n
     291:   00                          .byte 00
     292:   00                          .byte 00
     293:   00                          .byte 00
     294:   ff ff 00 00                 
    ...

000002a0 <system_adc_read_fast>:
     2a0:   e0c112                  addi    a1, a1, -32
     2a3:   11c9                    s32i.n  a12, a1, 4
     2a5:   21d9                    s32i.n  a13, a1, 8
     2a7:   31e9                    s32i.n  a14, a1, 12
     2a9:   5129                    s32i.n  a2, a1, 20
     2ab:   41f9                    s32i.n  a15, a1, 16
     2ad:   0109                    s32i.n  a0, a1, 0
     2af:   03fd                    mov.n   a15, a3
     2b1:   fff901                  l32r    a0, 298 <system_adc_read+0x40>
     2b4:   0000c0                  callx0  a0
     2b7:   4fbc                    beqz.n  a15, 2ef <system_adc_read_fast+0x4f>
     2b9:   fff6e1                  l32r    a14, 294 <system_adc_read+0x3c>
     2bc:   0c0c                    movi.n  a12, 0
     2be:   51d8                    l32i.n  a13, a1, 20
     2c0:   90dcd0                  addx2   a13, a12, a13
     2c3:   001d32                  l16ui   a3, a13, 0
     2c6:   1a13e7                  beq a3, a14, 2e4 <system_adc_read_fast+0x44>
     2c9:   902330                  addx2   a2, a3, a3
     2cc:   1122e0                  slli    a2, a2, 2
     2cf:   b30c                    movi.n  a3, 11
     2d1:   fff201                  l32r    a0, 29c <system_adc_read+0x44>
     2d4:   0000c0                  callx0  a0
     2d7:   f44020                  extui   a4, a2, 0, 16
     2da:   00a402                  movi    a0, 0x400
     2dd:   003d                    mov.n   a3, a0
     2df:   013047                  bltu    a0, a4, 2e4 <system_adc_read_fast+0x44>
     2e2:   043d                    mov.n   a3, a4
     2e4:   005d32                  s16i    a3, a13, 0
     2e7:   cc1b                    addi.n  a12, a12, 1
     2e9:   f4c0c0                  extui   a12, a12, 0, 16
     2ec:   ce9fc7                  bne a15, a12, 2be <system_adc_read_fast+0x1e>
     2ef:   11c8                    l32i.n  a12, a1, 4
     2f1:   21d8                    l32i.n  a13, a1, 8
     2f3:   31e8                    l32i.n  a14, a1, 12
     2f5:   41f8                    l32i.n  a15, a1, 16
     2f7:   0108                    l32i.n  a0, a1, 0
     2f9:   20c112                  addi    a1, a1, 32
     2fc:   f00d                    ret.n
     2fe:   00                          .byte 00
     2ff:   00                          .byte 00
     300:   ff ff 00 00                 
    ...
```

Comment: Cool detective work. Thanks! I was able to achieve my use case using this: https://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/52854/25931

Comment: @loadingnow can anyone clarify whether system_adc_read returns 0-1023 or whether it returns 1-1024?

Comment: @S.Imp I am not sure, but you should ask a separate question to clarify. It would be much more helpful for others who have the same question.